# Some pointers for creating a singly linked list in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, singly-linked-list

I have a uni assignment in which I have to implement a singly linked list that contains different objects that are derived from a common abstract base class called Shape.

I'll link to GitHub for the class implementation: [shapes.h](https://github.com/jkase/OOP-Assignment-3---Lists--inheritance-and-polymorphism/blob/master/shapes.h) , [shapes.cpp](https://github.com/jkase/OOP-Assignment-3---Lists--inheritance-and-polymorphism/blob/master/shapes.cpp). So far it consists of `Shape` and its derived class `Circle`. There'll also be `Rectangle`, `Point` and `Polygon` later.

I should now implement a singly linked list of these different kinds of shapes. So far I've come up with the following class prototype for the `List`-class and the `Node`-class:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node() {}

    friend class ShapeList;

    private:
    Shape* data;
    Node* nextNode;
};

class ShapeList
{
public:
    ShapeList(){head = NULL;}
    void Append(Shape& inData);

private:
    Node* head;
};
```

Adding elements `void Append(Shape& inData)` to a `ShapeList`-object should be able to be called from main in the following style:

```
ShapeList list1;

list1.Append( Circle(5,5,5) );
list1.Append( Rectangle( 4, 10, 2, 4) );
```

Given this information, how should I go about implementing `void Append(Shape& inData)`? I've tried several different approaches, but haven't come up with the correct solution so far.

It's also completely possible that the parameter to `Append` should be something else than `(Shape& inData)`.

edit:

I've implemented `Append(Shape& inData)` but it works only sometimes:

```
Circle circle1;
ShapeList list1;
list1.Append( circle1 );
```

but not with

```
ShapeList list1;
list1.Append ( Circle(5,5,5) )
```

So far my `Append()`-implementation looks as follows:

```
void ShapeList::Append(Shape& inData)
{
    //Create a new node
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->data=&inData;
    newNode->nextNode=NULL;

    //Create a temp pointer
    Node *tmp = head;

    if (tmp != NULL)
    {
        //Nodes already present in the list
        //Traverse to the end of the list
        while(tmp->nextNode != NULL)
            tmp = tmp->nextNode;

        tmp->nextNode=newNode;
    }

    else
        head=newNode;
}
```

Does that look ok to you guys?

Comment: You're going to be in big trouble if you create a linked list from temporary objects. You'll need to make copies or create them on the heap.

Comment: What were the approaches you tried, and what was wrong with them? Why didn't they work, and why doesn't knowing why they didn't work not lead you to a better solution?

Comment: I guess the first issue at hand is do you actually understand the issue between the stack and the heap (in terms of memory, not data structures)? This will be the first essential to truly understanding your solution.

Comment: @Caleb Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I'm mostly having problems with the given main() where I'm supposed to use the format list1.Append( Circle(5,5,5) ). I could make it work with for example Circle circle1(5,5,5) and then list1.(Append circle1).

Comment: @RageD No, I can't quite say I do. I think we're coming to that later on during the course.

Comment: @MarkRansom I can just copy the passed object in Append(), right?

Comment: @JKase In general, it will be very difficult to write a proper solution without this - but I assume if you have not gone over it in class yet (i.e. new/delete), then your instructor probably just wants you to use references and pointers.

Comment: Copying the passed object will be difficult, because you need to avoid object slicing. I'd stick to using object pointers.

Answer (score 1):

1. You probably want `Node` to be nested inside of `ShapeList` so its full name will be `ShapeList::Node`, not just `::Node`.
2. Since `Node` will own some data remotely, you probably need to define the big three for it.
3. In line with that, when you push something onto the list, the list will hold a dynamically allocated copy, not the original object.

Edit: `Append` should take a `Shape const &` rather than a `Shape &`. A reference to const can bind to a temporary object, but a reference to non-const cannot, so the calls using parameters that create temporary objects (e.g., `list.Append(Circle(5,5,5))`) won't compile if the parameter is a reference to non-const object.

I'd also change `Node::Node` to require that you pass it a parameter or two. As-is, your linked-list code is dealing with the internals of a Node more than I'd like. I'd change it to something like:

```
Node::Node(Shape const *d, Node *n=NULL) : data(d), nextNode(n) {}
```

Then in append, instead of:

```
Node* newNode = new Node();
newNode->data=&inData;
newNode->nextNode=NULL;
```

You'd use something like:

```
Node *newNode = new Node(&inData); // or, probably, `... = new Node(inData.clone());`
```

...and Node's ctor would handle things from there.

Also note that it's easier to add to the *beginning* of a linked list than to the end (it saves you from walking the whole list). If you really want to add to the end, it's probably worthwhile to save a pointer to the last node you added, so you can go directly to the end, rather than walking the whole list every time.

Comment: Thank you for good advice. See the edit I did, I think now that my problem actually doesn't concern linked list as much as it does just the implementation's syntax to work with the predefined call from main().

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged under 'homework', I will only point you to the good direction. This may be too basic or maybe it is enough for your needs...

In a typical situation, you would simply use a container that is already written such as std::list.

But for implementing your own linked list

When you start from the head member of the ShapeList, you should be able to traverse the entire list and find a node for which 'nextNode' has never been assigned.

This is where you want to add a new node.

Now thee a a few tricks to be make things work:

1- In C++, variables are not automatically initialized. You must therefore initialize the many values when you create a new node, especially the next node pointer.

2- Instead of having pointers to references, I suggest that either you create copies of Shapes, of use some kind of smart pointers to avoid copying.

3- Don't forget about memory management, when you destroy your linked list, you will have to destroy all nodes individually since.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful information right there. Could you please check the edit I did. I think my question actually concerns the syntax in the implementation and how to make it match the predefined call from main()

Answer (score 1):

One very nice implementation of the singly linked list is as a circular list with the "head" pointer pointing at the tail.  This makes it easy to insert at either the front or append to the end: in either case you create a fresh node, make the current tail point to it, and make it point to the current head, and then in the insert case make the head pointer point to the new node.

What you appear to be missing (other than what's already been pointed out: allocating, deallocating, and copying the nodes) is a way to know that you've actually created the list.  So you'll want to add in some sort of output - either an operator << or a print() routine, which will walk the list, and call your graphical objects' printing mechanisms in order.

You say that it is possible that the argument to Append might not be `Shape &data`.  Given the requirement of the calling convention specified, it should be:

```
Append( const Shape &data ) // provided shapes have copy constructors
    {
    Node *newNode = new Node( data ); // requires a constructor of Node that copies data to a freshly allocated location and sticks a pointer to that location in its data field - then Node's destructor needs to release that pointer.
    ... ( and the code to manipulate the existing list and newNode's next pointer )
    }
```

Among other things this makes responsibility for management clear and simple.

If you have a Node constructor that takes both a pointer to a Node and a Shape, you should be able to do Append in two lines - one allocating the new Node and calling the constructor appropriately, and one modifying a pointer to point to the new node.

I would add - based on your edit - that you absolutely need to do the allocation and copy inside Append.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to play around. Seems my question was  misguided to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to handle the polymorphic requirement (std::shared_ptr), demonstrated with the STL singly linked list...

```
typedef forward_list<shared_ptr<Shape>> ShapeList;

ShapeList list1;

list1.push_back(make_shared<Circle>(5,5,5));

list1.push_back(make_shared<Rectangle>(4, 10, 2, 4));
```

Here is how it would effect Node:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node() {}

    friend class ShapeList;

    private:
    shared_ptr<Shape> data;
    Node* nextNode;
};
```

and ShapeList...

```
class ShapeList
{
public:
    ShapeList(){head = NULL;}
    void Append(const shared_ptr<Shape>& inData);

private:
    Node* head;
};
```

Comment: This is homework (note the tag). The OP surely needs to *implement* the linked list, not use somebody else's implementation.

Comment: `[homework]` tag removed as part of cleanup, but the "uni assignment" is now in the first sentence.